# When I update Windows through Windows Update, SQL Server Express 2008 stops working

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, windows-firewall

In my scenario I have:

- A Windows 7 machine with SQL Server 2008 Express (Database Server)
- A Windows Vista machine with my software (Application Server) that reads and writes data to the Database Server.

Yesterday, after a Windows Update, my software is no longer able to access the database.

On the application server there is another program, and it accesses the same database correctly, there is also SQL Server Management Studio, and it accesses the same database correctly.

The only way I was able to reestablish the connection has been shut down the firewall on the database server.

On the database server firewall already exists a rule that allows the use of the 3 main ports used by SQL Server (1433 and the two others that i don't remember)

I tried to create a rule on application server firewall to allows my program to exit, but the problem is not that. In fact, as noted above, the problem is on firewall of the database server: turning it off fixes the problem.

Comment: do you know which update?

Comment: which machine was updated?

Comment: The update has affected both machines. I don't know which because, unfortunately, is set as automatic

Comment: You can see which update you have installed in control panel > windows update > history (I use an italian version of Windows and we have CRONOLOGIA).

Comment: Ok. I'm Italian also ;)

Comment: Last updates are: "Aggiornamento delle definizioni Microsoft Security Essentials - KB2310138"

Comment: Resolved opening port 1434 UDP! Yeah!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. If you've solved your problem, write an answer and marked it as the answer to your question.

Comment: How to mark it as the answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need open more ports.
Please look into this : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

Comment: And why the other one application installed on the same machine, which uses the same database, access correctly? :(

Comment: To me seems more strange that you have no problems with management studio on application server.

Comment: its strange though..did you able to resolve..??can you give us which update you got...!!

Comment: Last updates are:
"Aggiornamento delle definizioni Microsoft Security Essentials - KB2310138"